# The following message was thrown: Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was unexpected

Tags: android, flutter, dart, testing, widget

In the widget tesitng in flutter . Every time I face this issue

I have doubt in method to dirrect the widget
await tester.pumpWidget(  UserDetails();

```
void main() {
  var emailField = find.byKey(Key("fname-field"));
  var passwordField = find.byKey(Key("lname-field"));
  var passwordField1 = find.byKey(Key("enumber-field"));
  var signInButton = find.text("SUBMIT");
  group("UserDetails  Screen test", () {
    testWidgets("Check the buttons in User screen",
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(  UserDetails()
      );
      await tester.pump();
      expect(emailField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(signInButton, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordField1, findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

here I got error like this

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK
> ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> message was thrown: Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the
> running of the current test, and at least one was unexpected.
>
> The following FirebaseException was thrown attaching to the render
> tree: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created -
> call Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: Is there more to the error message?  Does it describe what the exceptions actually were?

Comment: The following FirebaseException was thrown attaching to the render tree:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: And have you tried calling `Firebase.initializeApp()` first?

Comment: when i put code inside the main function .it still  show same error

Comment: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Comment: IIRC `Firebase.initializeApp` is asynchronous.  Did you `await` it?

Comment: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null). i got this error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you tried finding the widgets before the page was even pumped.

Change the scope like so:

```
void main() {
  group("UserDetails  Screen test", () {
    testWidgets("Check the buttons in User screen",
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(UserDetails());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await tester.pump();

      var emailField = find.byKey(Key("fname-field"));
      var passwordField = find.byKey(Key("lname-field"));
      var passwordField1 = find.byKey(Key("enumber-field"));
      var signInButton = find.text("SUBMIT");


      expect(emailField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(signInButton, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordField1, findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: still I got same error

Comment: I added a `pumpAndSettle`, does it work?

Comment: nope,still I got error

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebase you should mock you firebase first.
I think it will work for you
Wrap your widget to MaterialAapp and Scaffold
Sometimes your widget hierarcy needs size of context that came from scaffold and MaterialApp context.

```
void main() {
   var emailField = find.byKey(Key("fname-field"));
   var passwordField = find.byKey(Key("lname-field"));
   var passwordField1 = find.byKey(Key("enumber-field"));
   var signInButton = find.text("SUBMIT");
   group("UserDetails  Screen test", () {
       testWidgets("Check the buttons in User screen",
           (WidgetTester tester) async {
                await tester.pumpWidget(
                    MaterialApp(
                        home: Scaffold(
                            body: UserDetails(),
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                await tester.pump();
                expect(emailField, findsOneWidget);
                expect(passwordField, findsOneWidget);
                expect(signInButton, findsOneWidget);
                expect(passwordField1, findsOneWidget);
        });
    });
}
```